# Passing script string to ssh from within a bash script function - variable evaluation problem

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, quoting

I'm trying to write a bash script that runs a remote script via ssh as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
logfilepattern="*drupal*.gz php*.gz error*.gz"
function getlogcounts {
    echo "in getlogcounts"
    echo  $1
    echo  $2

    ssh $1 bash -c '  \  #script string starts here
    cd $2
    for file in `ls $logfilepattern`
    do
     ls -l $file
    done
'
}

getlogcounts me@remoteserver.com "/var/log/mylogs"
```

`$1` and `$2` seem to come across ok into the function, but inside the script string they don't appear to have a value... hence `cd $2` evaluates to `cd` and `ls $logfilepattern` evaluates to `ls`.

Comment: Take a look at [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: also, that for loop is pointless. It can be replaced with `ls -l $logfilepattern`

Comment: Thanks @cas . The for loop is there cause I'm trying to do a bit more which I omitted for clarity (my mistake!)... it should really be `for file in `ls     $logfilepattern` do zcat $file | wc -l`
function getlogcounts {
 echo in getlogcounts
 echo  "$1"
 echo  "$2"
 
 ssh "$1" bash -c '
 cd "$2"
 for file in $logfilepattern
 do
   zcat $file | wc -l
 done
' 
}

Now I'm getting:
bash: -c: option requires an argument

Sorry for the formatting... noob at this...

Comment: even so, don't parse ls (see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).  `for file in $logpattern;  do ... ; done` is sufficient, and works better.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version which has been simplified and, more importantly, quoting has been corrected (double-quotes around variables, single quotes around non-variable text where required)

```
#!/bin/bash
logfilepattern='*drupal*.gz php*.gz error*.gz'

function getlogcounts {
    echo in getlogcounts
    echo "$1"
    echo "$2"

    ssh "$1" "cd $2 ; ls -l $logfilepattern"
}

getlogcounts me@remoteserver.com /var/log/mylogs
```

Answer (score 2):

You're executing a script on the remote machine. That script happens to contain `$2` and `$logfilepattern` (the text between single quotes is passed literally as an argument to the `ssh` command, so it's a code snippet to execute on the other side). These refer to variables of the shell running on the remove side.

Actually, you're running two shells on the remote side, but not usefully so. SSH always invokes a shell; you can pass it multiple arguments but they're just joined with spaces in between. The shell on the remote side executes

```
bash -c   \  #script string starts here
cd $2
…
```

The first line invokes `bash` with two arguments: `-c` and a single space. This invokes a shell to do nothing. The rest of the remote command is executed in the shell invoked by SSH.

The simple way to do what you're trying to do is

```
ssh "$1" "cd $2 && ls -l $logfilepattern"
```

Notes:

- [Parsing the output of `ls` is pointless](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs): `` for file in `ls *` `` is a complex way of writing `for file in *`, except that parsing the output of `ls` breaks if the file names contain special characters.
- Both `$2` and `$logfilepattern` are parsed as part of the script that's executed on the remote side. If they contain something like `$(touch foo)`, then that piece of code will be executed. In this particular use case, it isn't necessarily a problem, but it's something you need to be aware of.
- Using `&&` after `cd` ensures that the `ssh` command will return immediately with a failure status if the `cd` command fails.

If you want to pass content unmodified to a remote shell over SSH, using the command line alone is problematic, because whatever you pass is expanded on the remote side. One trick that often works (but not always, it depends on the configuration of SSH both on the client and on the server) is to use variables whose name begins with `LC_`; these are assumed to be information about the locale, and often transmitted.

```
LC_DIRECTORY=$2 LC_LOGFILEPATTERN=$logfilepattern ssh "$1" 'cd "$LC_DIRECTORY" && ls -l $LC_LOGFILEPATTERN'
```

Note the quoting:

- The command to execute on the remote machine is `cd "$LC_DIRECTORY" && ls -l $LC_LOGFILEPATTERN`. It's in single quotes to pass that literal text as an argument to the `ssh` command.
- `$LC_DIRECTORY` is in double quotes in the script that's executed on the remote side so that the `cd` command is invoked on the content of the variable.
- `LC_LOGFILEPATTERN` is not double-quoted because it's a whitespace-separated list of wildcard patterns, which is precisely how an unquoted variable expansion is treated.

If you're unable to transmit variables, you'll need to add a layer of quoting to protect variables whose value contains special characters.

```
q_directory=$(printf %sa "$2" | sed s/\'/\'\\\'\'/g)
q_directory="'${directory%a}'"
q_logfilepattern=$(printf %sa "$logfilepattern" | sed s/\'/\'\\\'\'/g)
q_logfilepattern="'${q_logfilepattern%a}'"
ssh "$1" "logfilepattern=$q_logfilepattern; cd $q_logfilepattern && ls \$logfilepattern"
```